# import video file with reactJs in symfony

Tags: javascript, reactjs, symfony, webpack, twig

ok I need to display a video in my react component but my webpackEncore returns me the error that it can't find my VideoMp4 file I use react with symfony.

error :
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

my code :

```js
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import { useEffect } from 'react/cjs/react.development';
import video from '../video/videoHome.mp4'

function FondEcran() {
  return (
    <div className="background">
      <video muted autoPlay loop>
        <source src={video} type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </div>
  );
}

class fondEcran extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback(){
        render(<FondEcran/>,this)
    
    }
}

customElements.define('fond-ecran' , fondEcran)
```

Comment: Have you tried using the path to the video file for the src? `src="../video/videoHome.mp4"`

Comment: yeah i've tried but didn't work